# Is $(\mathbf{V} \cap \mathbf{W})^{\bot}=(\mathbf{V}^{\bot} \cap \mathbf{W}^{\bot})$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Is $(\mathbf{V} \cap \mathbf{W})^{\bot}=(\mathbf{V}^{\bot} \cap \mathbf{W}^{\bot})$? I tried element-chasing, but I am getting confused when trying to determine mutual containment.

Comment: Try examples. Try at least a few examples to see if it works.

Comment: And don't look back at this page before that, because someone is going to post an answer soon, thereby ruining this for you!

Comment: Guilty... Maybe I should temporarily hide it, but I suppose it's too late.  Dear Jared, I hope that I have not ruined your joy of discovery.

Comment: By the way, $\LaTeX$'s way to say 'perpendicular' is `\perp` (which gives a $\perp$) and not `\bot` (which results in a $\bot$)

Comment: No. You should have union on the right hand side

Answer (score 6):

No.  Try $W=\{0\}$, $V\neq\{0\}$.

What is true is that the perp of the span of two spaces is the intersection of the perps: $(V\vee W)^\perp=V^\perp\cap W^\perp$.

Answer (score 3):

If the ambient space has dimension $n$, then taking the orthogonal complement takes a subspace of dimension $k$ to a subspace of dimension $n-k$. Intersection in general reduces the dimension. So your equation looks suspect.

A nice analogy is from propositional logic: the orthogonal complement is similar to negation, and intersection is similar to logical and. So according to de Morgan's laws, if in one side of the equation you have $\cap$, in the other side you should have the dual operator, viz. $+$ (what Jonas uses $\lor$ for).