# Proving properties of orthogonal subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces

If $M$ and $N$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that $$(M+N)^\bot=M^\bot \cap N^\bot$$ and $$(M \cap N)^\bot = M^\bot +N^\bot $$

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45087/proof-about-orthogonal-subspaces) previous question, but I cannot seem to make sense of the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1) To show that $(M+N)^{\perp}\subseteq M^{\perp}$ and $(M+N)^{\perp}\subseteq N^{\perp}$,

$\;\;\;$you can use that $M\subseteq M+N$ and $N\subseteq M+N$.  This gives $(M+N)^{\perp}\subseteq M^{\perp}\cap N^{\perp}$.

2) To show that $M^{\perp}\cap N^{\perp}\subseteq (M+N)^{\perp}$, let $x\in M^{\perp}\cap N^{\perp}$ and show that $\langle x,y\rangle=0$

$\;\;\;$if $y=m+n\in M+N$.

3) To show the second equality (using the first), you can use

$\;\;\;M^{\perp}+N^{\perp}=\big((M^{\perp}+N^{\perp})^{\perp}\big)^{\perp}=\big((M^{\perp})^{\perp}\cap(N^{\perp})^{\perp}\big)^{\perp}=(M\cap N)^{\perp}.$

Comment: What is the significance of the $\subseteq$ notation?

Comment: $A\subseteq B$ just means that A is a subset of B.

Comment: I don't understand why $(M+N)^{\perp}\subseteq M^{\perp}$ and $(M+N)^{\perp}\subseteq N^{\perp}$.  I understand that $M\subseteq M+N$ and $N\subseteq M+N$.  Can you really just apply the perp operator to both sides of the equation like it is an exponent?

Comment: If $A\subseteq B$, then $B^{\perp}\subseteq A^{\perp}$ since $x\cdot b=0$ for all $b\in B \implies x\cdot a=0$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: For the second part, could you elaborate more?  I really don't understand $\cap$s.

Comment: If $x\in M^{\perp}\cap N^{\perp}$, that just means that $x\in M^{\perp}$ and $x \in N^{\perp}$.