# Understanding a disprove example on Orthogonality subject

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I was trying to disprove the following thoerem:

> If $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $(A\cap B)^\bot = A^\bot \cup B^\bot$.

I know that the theorem is not true, but my book gave the following example (other language):

> Consider $A=Sp\{(1,0)\}$ and $B=Sp\{(0,1)\}$. We get $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $(A\cap B)^\bot =\mathbb{R}^2$. We also get $A^\bot = B$ and $B^\bot = A$ so $A^\bot \cup B^\bot = A\cup B \neq \mathbb{R}^2 $ (for example $(1,1)\not \in U\cup W$).

I don't understand why this example works. Isn't $A\cup B=Sp\{(0,1),(1,0)\}=\mathbb{R}^2$? then we get that it does works.

I also read the previous thread on the subject ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23025/is-mathbfv-cap-mathbfw-bot-mathbfv-bot-cap-mathbfw-bot?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the intersection of subspaces is always a subspace, but the (*set theoretic*) union of subspaces is only very rarely a subspace (e.g. if one subspace contains the other), it rather mostly looks like a *cross*, just as $A\cup B$ in the given example.

Put that formally, we simply don't have $\rm{span}(A\cup B)=A\cup B$ while we do have $\rm{span}(A\cap B)=A\cap B$ if $A$ and $B$ are subspaces.

However, the formula can be corrected, at least in a finite dimension space, this does hold:
$$(A\cap B)^\perp=\rm{span}(A^\perp\cup B^\perp)\,.$$

Comment: So what does $A\cup B$ contain?

Comment: It contains all elements of $A$ and all elements of $B$ and no more elements. That's the horizontal and vertical line.

Comment: What is the domination of $A\cup B=Sp\{(0,1)\}\cup\{(1,0)\}$?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant Dimension instead of domination. Is it 2?

Comment: Ah, the dimension? Yes, $A\cup B$ generates the whole two dimensional space, as $(x,0)\in A$ and $(0,y)\in B$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, so $(x,y)=(x,0)+(0,y)\in \mathrm{span}(A\cup B)$ though if both $x,y$ are nonzero, $(x,y)\notin A\cup B$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that $\mathbb R^{2}=A\cup B$. $(1,1) \in \mathbb R^{2} \setminus A\cup B$.